android emulator not working on API 29 and later

when I run the app on any emulator with API level 29 and above it shows only as in the picture and at this moment its state in the device manager is: starting up. Then after some time, the android studio shows a notification with this message:
The emulator process for AVD Pixel_7_Pro_API_34 has terminated.
The Logcat panel shows that the device is offline, so I can't get any error messages.
current andoid studio details: Android Studio Koala | 2024.1.1
Build #AI-241.15989.150.2411.11948838, built on June 10, 2024
Runtime version: 17.0.10+0--11609105 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
windows details:
Edition Windows 11 Pro
Version 23H2
Installed on    ‎22/‎09/‎2023
OS build    22631.3737
Experience  Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.22700.1009.0
device details :
Processor   Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8550U CPU @ 1.80GHz   1.99 GHz
Installed RAM   16.0 GB (15.9 GB usable)
System type 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor
Pen and touch   No pen or touch input is available for this display

use bluestack , andriod emulator will lag even if it works

Have you tried to reset existing emulator definitions and images stored in C:\Users\%username%\.android\avd?

@Robert what do you mean by reset?

Delete and restart a fresh avd instance. I would also recommend to check the selected emulator acceleration https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration#vm-windows

@Robert I have tried deleting and creating new AVD instances multiple times with different devices but nothing helped
